# Xcode Safe Area Glitch With iPhone SE & 4s

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoa-touch, autolayout

I was setting up constraints when I realize things don't look right on iPhone SE and 4s. As shown below, the safe area is out of bounds. Any way to get around it so I can get an accurate look at my view?

It works alright on iPhone 8, 8+ and X

[image: iPhone X Layout]

But on 4s and SE, this happens, so many errors pop up despite it working fine when built and run on simulator

[image: iPhone 4s Layout]
[image: It works ok when built]

Comment: are you using auto-layouts ?

Comment: yes I am using auto-layout

Comment: are you giving the fixed height and width to the views ?

Comment: No, only the aspect ratios and distance from edge of safe area. I should have clarified that I only have this issue on storyboard, not when built. Thing is, is there a setting for safe area that fixes this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will sometimes glitch when viewing it in main.storyboard, but when the project builds and runs, it will reinitiate those constraints and follow them to build the view.

I recommend that you try running the project, and all should be fixed.

Comment: Thank you, it does work when built, but I would like to have the safe area work correctly so I can get an accurate preview when working on more complex layout. Is there a way to fix that?

Comment: Dennis Lau, you can try setting constraints on the SE, and that should maybe look better. From experience, some items you can add onto the view just don't work at all, and will not show in the correct form for their constraints. On the other hand, I can actually see a red arrow next to the view controller seen on the top left. Please click on this, and look at the errors you are being given. if you don't understand them, be sure to let me know and I will continue to help.

Comment: Hey D-A UK thanks for helping that's so kind of you! I think you were right that it's a glitch with xcode interpreting constraints in relation to safe area cos, despite the red arrow error, everything works completely fine when built and run in simulator, so the constraint logic should be ok. Do you know of any way to get around this glitch?

Comment: No problem. Be sure to tick my answer as the right answer to help others who have the same problem find an answer easily. Sometimes if you stick data in the holder i.e. an image the image view in your case, then it will sometimes correct itself because it know what content size it has got to deal with, although if that doesn't work, then I think you will just have to accept that it won't work, and use the simulator to preview content.